# MVC routing with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC3 app.
For a URI like http://app/survey/Test i have the following survey/{name} which works great.

This survey controller loads a bunch of questions
Each question has a bunch of possible answers
The possible answers are put in to a DropdownListBox or some other List friendly control

Now if a user hit a URI like http://app/survey/Test?city=London I want to somehow figure out in my Model.Question[i].PossibleAnswers collection that London is meant to be the default value for the Question "City".

If the user hit a URI like http://app/survey/Test?gender=Male&city=London&something=SomethingElse
Then i want the Test survey to display
And it's gender question defaulted to Male
It's city question defaulted to London
It's something question defaulted to SomethingElse

Make any sense?
Anybody have any idea how to set this up?

It's a bit vague, so sorry about that but the best way I can think of describing this.

Thanks

Comment: Just a rough thought.. But since your controller already is responding to http://app/survey/test, you could create a check in your controller action that checks for query-parameters. If certain parameters are filled you could setup your Viewmodel (assuming your using strongtyped viewmodels) with the default values for a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model binding  as below and then pass

> SurveyModel

to your controllor action in action method your can use SurveyModel. id for City SurveyModel.id2 ,etc

```
  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            IValueProvider valueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider;

            string id = valueProvider.GetValueOrNullString("id");
            string id2 = valueProvider.GetValueOrNullString("id2");
            string id3 = valueProvider.GetValueOrNullString("id3");
            string id4 = valueProvider.GetValueOrNullString("id4");

            return new SurveyModel {Id = id, Id2 = id2, Id3 = id3, Id4 = id4};
        }
```

Refer [Google Links for More details](http://www.google.com/search?q=Mdoe%20binding%20in%20asp.net%20mvc3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=WgI&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&source=hp&q=Mdoe%20binding%20in%20asp.net%20mvc&pbx=1&oq=Mdoe%20binding%20in%20asp.net%20mvc&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=11671l11671l0l11942l1l1l0l0l0l0l92l92l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=acd86c1ec691f977&biw=1400&bih=833)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything, other than to specify your model in your `HttpGet` action, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(Survey survey)
{ }
```

If you specify a model in the GET action, the querystring values will be passed into the model, since they are consumed by the `QueryStringValueProvider`, which makes them available to be bound to your model without any further action on your part.